# MacBook Pro Temperature Issues (tlp and cpufreq used)

Tags: macbook, overheating, fan, temperature

I recently installed the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a MacBook Pro, and I have noticed some overheating issues. Specifically, I used **indicator-sensors** and **psensors** to monitor the temperature, and the average is approximately 55 degrees celsius. How significant is the overheating?

To try and lower the temperature, I used **cpufreq**, and set it to 'powersave' mode. In addition, I have installed **TLP**, and during the measurements it had already been running for an hour, in AC mode.

I'd like to maximize the lifetime of my processor, which means minimizing the temperature as much as possible. Are there any other packages or methods to maintain a better temperature?

Comment: Another thought would be to get Bigger fans and/or Over-volt the fans. Also consider using `fancontrol` and/or `lm-sensors` ... the configs for PWM are generally located somewhere in `/sys/class/hwmon`

Answer (score 3):

You should install macfanctld as suggested by:

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/11/ppa-install-fan-control-ubuntu-macbook/

Comment: I've installed it, and run 'macfanctld' in the terminal. Do I need to configure it, or by default does it have ideal settings for a Mac?

Comment: upstart should run macfanctld automatically, but you can run it in the foreground with "sudo macfanctld -f" to debug its behavior.  Sometimes you need to tweak which fans it reads via /etc/macfanctld.conf.